# FragmentActivity with ActionBar

Tags: android

I am trying out `FragmentActivity` with `ActionBar`... To implement the tab version with SWIPE in all android versions as `TabHost` is deprecated.

I got this sample project which works just fine on version more than API 11: http://goo.gl/b4ly7W

I would like to make it work even on phones that are lesser than API 11. According to Google Developer website I have to use `support-v7` jar files I tried it but then it didn't work.

Has someone tried this out on versions below API 11? If so how to fix this issue?

Comment: can you please post your code here?

Comment: I am trying the same code. There is no difference.... The following I tried after couple of research: 

I did the following:

1. extends ActionBarActivity instead of extends FragmentActivity (you will need to import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity)

2. change your imports to look like
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

Comment: You mean to say is, above api 11 its working and below api 11 its not working right?

Comment: mmmm ok let check it out and let you know ok sanjana

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54409/discussion-between-pratik-and-sanjana).